# Viewing pdf file with TallComponents Web PdfViewer from orginal folder

Tags: pdfviewer

i using TallComponents Web PdfViewer to viewing pdf file inside asp.net page
but all pdf file must be in some folder (called "basePath") and when i viewed them from other location it's copy to base path and viewed from here !
please help me how can view pdf file from original location ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by yourself because this project is in opensourse area [codeplex link.](https://pdfwebviewer1.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#source/Storage/FileSystemStorageProvider.cs)
Check the **FileSystemStorageProvider.cs**

Comment: can you give me example ?